# Dashboard Controller Setup in Sonata Admin

Tags: sonata-admin

I am new to Sonata Admin.

I got dashboard template in it, but couldn't find controller of dashboard, I need dynamic data in dashboard file.

[image]

Can anyone help me?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The /dashboard is default rendered by the CoreController class ... so in my opinion its the best approach to override its dashboardAction and do your own stuff there.

To match the /dashboard route to your controller, edit your routing.yml and add a routing entry for it.

Hop that helps.

Answer (score 0):

you should use sonata blocks to customize your dashboard:

https://sonata-project.org/bundles/block/master/doc/reference/your_first_block.html

and configure them in your config:

https://sonata-project.org/bundles/admin/2-0/doc/reference/dashboard.html